# Using Insert when certain length of string is given as input in C#

Tags: c#, insert

What I am trying to do is if user input four characters like 0500, I want to add ":" after second character so it becomes 05:00. From trial and error it does't seems to insert correctly.

So part of my codes is

```
        string timeInput = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] timeSplit = timeInput.Split(':');

        if(timeInput.Length == 4) { // if string = four
            timeInput = timeInput.Insert(1, ":");
            }
```

Comment: You missed the correct index buddy. It should be 2 and not 1.

Comment: don't mix the terms "string" and "character". I've edited your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't split the string by ':' if your input doesn't contain any ':'. So you don't need the variable `timeSplit`. You can do it like this:

```
string timeInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (timeInput.Length == 4)   // if input = "0500" -> true
    timeInput = timeInput.Insert(2, ":");
Console.WriteLine(timeInput);    // Output: 05:00
```

With `timeInput.Insert(1, ":")` you would get "0:500" as output.

Comment: yes, because what I am trying to do here is if input like 05:00 is go through split but if 0500 is entered I want to change it to 05:00.

Comment: oh I get it, have to declare split after going if statement

Comment: yea my silly mistake there for putting 1, just realise now

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
timeInput = timeInput.Insert(1, ":");
```

with

```
timeInput = timeInput.Insert(2, ":");
```

to insert the `:` at the second index

```
string  0 5 0 0
index  0|1|2|3|4
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `Insert` method is the index number where you want to insert any character, after two digit the index number is `2` so It should be `2` instead `1`

```
timeInput = timeInput.Insert(2, ":");
```

and why do you you spliting the input using `:` where you haven't inseted `:` into it? splite after innsert `:` is the correct one I guess

```
string timeInput = Console.ReadLine();
if(timeInput.Length == 4) 
 { // if string = four
    timeInput = timeInput.Insert(2, ":");
 }
string[] timeSplit = timeInput.Split(':');
```

Answer (score 0):

A single character in a `string` is called a `char`

Although the length of the `string` is 4 the indexing starts with 0!

```
string timeInput = "0500"
```

When you index it it would look like this:

> timeInput[0] -> 0
>
> timeInput[1] -> 5
>
> timeInput[2] -> 0
>
> timeInput[3] -> 0

this is why you need to put the `:` on position 2

```
if(timeInput.Length == 4) // if string = four
{ 
    timeInput = timeInput.Insert(2, ":");
}
```